# How to split a particular single word in a comma separated multiple word string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like below:

```
string numbers = "one,two,three,four";
```

I want to split the word "two" from the string "numbers". The problem is that i am not sure the word "two" will not be always exist on the second position. It may change it is position dynamically as changed by the application.

How do i split the word "two" safely and i should have rest of the string as below?

```
string numbers ="one,three,four";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "split"? You want to remove it?

Comment: is `numbers` always a comma-separated list like you have shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Regex.Replace` function to remove the substring `two` and it's following or preceding comma from the input string .

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"two,|,two", "");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rQ0gG7/1)